# Boolean statement form c++

Tags: c++, boolean

Could somebody please help me read these statements? for some reason i can't find a simple and straight forward explanation online:

x = (xx = 40) ? false : true

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still confused. Does it read: if statement (x) is true then xx = 40? what if it is false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?` is a ternary operator. If the first expression evaluates to `true`, the argument before the `:` is returned, otherwise, the argument after the `:` is returned.

Here, you assign `40` to `xx`. The assignment operator (`=`) returns the value it assigns - 40, in this case. Since it isn't `0`, it's considered to be `true`, so the ternary expression will return `false`.

To sum it up: `xx` will be assigned with `40`, and `x` with `false`.